# Facebook Fan Page - Question

Tags: facebook

If I create a Facebook page then is it possible for anyone to know which user has created this fan page or who owns this fan page?

I want to keep my personal facebook page separate from my fan page. In a nutshell I want to hide my personal identity from a fan page .

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Facebook Profile and Facebook Fan Page are separate things / entities, once you create page in Facebook you will be admin of the page and you can moderate the page but there is no way to other users know who is the admin of page. So there will not be any harm to our personal identity by creating a fan page.